# How to update data from database by clicking button with angularjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, api, datagridview

I am new with angular so got issue. Main idea of my mini project is that I have to show data from database. Everything should be shown in View by calling api and request to database.To show current data now is working. Now I want to update data from database by clicking button, but unfortunately I don't what kind of function I have to write in my controller.
Here is my DataGridView.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $resource, $http, $routeParams, $location) {

    var Users = $resource('/api/tables');
    $scope.users = Users.query(function () {
        //console.log(user);
    });
});
```

Here is my (API) Tables1Controller.cs ,only main method

```
public string GetTables()
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return jss.Serialize(db.Tables);
        }
```

And here is my Index where I show data, and I added button

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td>{{user.Id}}</td>
            <td>{{user.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.Surename}}</td>
            <td>{{user.Address}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div ng-repeat=>
    {{ user.Name }}
    a
</div>
<div class="btn btn-danger">Button</div>
```

At _Layout.cshtml I added ng-app and ng-controller in body. What would be the best solution?

Edit: I know it should start something with ng-click near button, but I don't kow how to write function to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

In js file I added:

```
$scope.update = (function () {
        var Users = $resource('/api/tables');
        $scope.users = Users.query(function () {
        });
    });
```

and in html file I did button like this:

```
<div class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="update()">Refresh</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using ASP.Net MVC with Angular. In this case, 'controller' is confusing because it means different thing in MVC and Angular.

Back to your question, you need two things

1. Angular: Use $http.post to sent data when  user clicked the button. The URL of $http.post should match #2's route.
2. MVC controller: Add a HttpPost controller to receive data from browser. And run insert command to save data in your storage.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you can read about ngResource, for example here http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/